# C# Theora encoder?

Tags: c#, encoder, ogg-theora

I want to live stream images I receive from a third party service to a HTML5 video.
Looks like the best option is to encode the images in the theora format.

Anyone knows a good theora encoder for c#

Comment: Check here: http://wiki.xiph.org/index.php/TheoraSoftwareEncoders

Comment: "Good" video encoders usually imply "fast."  As such, they're unlikely to be packaged as managed-code components, especially the open source ones.  It is very likely that your solution includes a separate process running ffmpeg2theora, controlled by your c# app.

Comment: On a side note - you might need to encode in different formats - as not all browsers support the same format yet.... (The latest realses might - but most users aren't on the latest version (ie6...)

FF: OGV
CHROME: WEBM/MP4
SAFARI: MP4 (I think)
IE:MP4

Comment: It does not need to be a managed code API, I can invoke from C# But it cant be a executeable, the third party sertvice sends me images 15 times per second so the C# web server needs to decode this on the fly and output to the html5 video stream